# gcc linking two files not working in macOS

Tags: c, macos, gcc

For my compiler course, I'm following the [Incremental Approach to Compiler Construction](http://scheme2006.cs.uchicago.edu/11-ghuloum.pdf) by Abdulaziz Ghuloum with the accompanying [tutorial](https://github.com/namin/inc/blob/master/docs/tutorial.pdf). At some point, we have the following two .c files:

`runtime.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("%d\n", entry_point());
    return 0;
}
```

`ctest.c`

```c
int entry_point() {
    return 7;
}
```

The author then runs the following commands:

```bash
$ gcc -Wall ctest.c runtime.c -o test
[bunch of warnings]
$ ./test
7
$
```

But when I run `$ gcc -Wall ctest.c runtime.c -o test` I get the following error:

```
runtime.c:9:20: error: implicit declaration of function 'entry_point' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    printf("%d\n", entry_point());
```

I want to be able to compile and link my two .c files the same way the author did using gcc, but it keeps throwing me that error. I've been doing some [research](https://randerson112358.medium.com/link-c-programs-7282712fca1f) but the same command (`$ gcc file1.c file2.c -o combined`) keeps coming up. Help would be appreciated.

I'm running this on MacOS Monterey 12.6 and doing `gcc --version` displays:

```
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On macOS, the default compiler is `clang`, not `gcc`. The later is just a symlink to `clang` so that's something to keep in mind.

Clang sees the call to `entry_point()` in `runtime.c` and doesn't know it yet. Traditional C for such an undefined function is to assume it returns `int` and does not accept arguments. But Clang goes the safe route by default and instead of just warning about it, treats this as an error since most of the time this assumption is just false and may cause runtime issues.

You have multiple options:

- Add a header file that defines `int entry_point(void);` and `#include` it in your `runtime.c`.
- Add the line `int entry_point(void);` near the top of your `runtime.c`.
- Pass `-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration` to the compiler.

Comment: Thank you!!! I was looking for something like the third option.

Comment: It's better to go for option 1 in "real" code, though. It really is a serious issue and suppressing these errors is a bad habit that is likely to bite you someday. If it's just for code you're copy & pasting and plan to throw away, suppressing the error is fine, of course.